# Simple CI for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, continuous-integration

I'm looking for a continuous integration server that:

- Allows me to simply add my clients Rails projects as builds, checking out from Github on a new commit.  These are NOT public projects.
- Allows me to notify results into a campfire room.
- Allows me to install services that I might need such as Postgres or Redis, so probably not anything that's hosted and run by someone else.
- Is easily hosted

Are there any solutions out there that are suited to this?  I've looked at Hudson and Teamcity, but was wondering what else there was out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Travis CI](http://travis-ci.org/)

Comment: From what I can see this is only for open source projects.  I'm talking more about a set of client projects for a client.  I've updated the question.

Comment: Yes, it's currently available for open-source projects only, but they are planning to add support for private github repositories in the nearest future.

Comment: They've added support for closed-source projects: https://travis-ci.com/plans

Answer (score 11):

Well, as long as we're spamming our own products, why don't I add mine :)

[CircleCI](https://circleci.com) does everything you said and more.

Security, all your databases, github, heroku and campfire+hipchat integration, automatic parallelism, incredibly fast builds, and can be set up in moments.

If you're interested in some of the rationale, check out the [StackOverflow podcast](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/se-podcast-22/) where Joel and I talk about it :)

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [TestPilot CI](http://testpilot.me)

It supports private repos in a high security sandbox environment, automatically connects to Github to trigger builds when code changes, notifies by Campfire or email, and has an open source build environment (which already includes the most common dependencies, like Redis, Mongo, Postgres, Riak, Mysql, Sqlite3, RabbitMQ etc.)

I'm one of the developers behind it and we are constantly developing new features based on customer demand, so we'd love to hear what you think of it.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely check out [Tddium](http://www.tddium.com). Sign up for a free 14-day trial: there's no need to wait for a beta invitation.

It's fully hosted in sandboxed VM's, supports private Git repositories, and does CI through git hooks. Campfire integration is included.

Tddium currently supports:

- Full Heroku integration, including a Heroku-approved addon
- RSpec, Cucumber, Spinach, Test::Unit, and Jasmine (via Webkit)
- MySQL, Postgres, Mongo
- Redis, Memcached, Riak
- Solr and ThinkingSphinx
- Capybara, Selenium, WebKit, Culerity
- Ruby 1.9.3, 1.9.2, 1.8.7, and REE
- CouchDB and RabbitMQ